# Saving as PDF and Retaining Text

Tags: pdf, ocr

I have literally tried all day to resolve this simple problem, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. We have a web based CRM system which creates some documents. I am using Chrome to save this as a PDF file.

The PDF file is created fine and the text is editable. I'm using Xfinium PDF to read the PDF and extract certain parts of the document. When I create the PDF using chrome save as PDF then the text is editable. However, the text is highly fragmented. Almost every letter is treated as an individual fragment.

I have found a way around this, but it's not the easiest. Basically the document has a field with several headings such as "Quantity:" followed by the quantity, I would have liked to scan the document for quantity and then save the value in a variable. However, what I have to do is look for "Q" followed by "u"... etc.... and then capture the value.

I've tried various print to pdf options but almost all do not retain the text but flatten everything into a single image. Adobe PDF can OCR this and create a searchable document, but this is an extra process.

I also found win2pdf which has an OCR function, but this also isn't working correctly.

I'm not enjoying the PDF format to be honest. I foolishly assumed that the text would have a label name assigned to it. I'm also not loving our CRM system, it's a closed system I have no API for, so extracting our own information from it is proving to be difficult.

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

Comment: Consider a toolkit like LEADTOOLS which has libraries that could help with what you are trying to do. The LEADTOOLS [Virtual Printer](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/pr/introduction.html) library captures the print job and processes the document so you would not need to save the PDF to disk. After that, you can use something like the [Document Analyzer](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/tutorials/dotnet-console-parse-data-with-the-document-analyzer.html) library to search the text of the PDF directly for the Quantity pattern. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)